# How to programmatically highlight word between parentheses in word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm trying to highlight text between parentheses in a word document, but my code highlights only the parentheses. Here is my code:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object textf = "(";
    object texs = ")";
    object color = Color.Cyan;
    object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    acWord.Application.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();

    acWord.Application.Selection.Find.HitHighlight(ref textf, ref color, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

}
```

Comment: You need to select ranges rather than finding characters. Search for the Selection and Range objects in word vba...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845882.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this.

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object fileName = "xxxxx"; //The filepath goes here
    string textToFind = "xxxxx"; //The text to find goes here
    Word.Application word = new Word.Application();
    Word.Document doc = new Word.Document();
    object missing = System.Type.Missing;
    try
    {
        doc = word.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref missing, 
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        doc.Activate();
        foreach (Word.Range docRange in doc.Words)
        {
            if(docRange.Text.Trim().Equals(textToFind,
               StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                docRange.HighlightColorIndex = 
                  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdDarkYellow;
                docRange.Font.ColorIndex = 
                  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdWhite;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

You can try this as well.

```
using System.Drawing;
using Spire.Doc;
using Spire.Doc.Documents;

namespace WordImage
{
    class ImageinWord
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create Document
            Document document = new Document();
            document.LoadFromFile(@"E:\Work\Documents\WordDocuments\References.docx");

            TextSelection[] text = document.FindAllString("forming", false, true);
            foreach (TextSelection seletion in text)
            {
                seletion.GetAsOneRange().CharacterFormat.HighlightColor = Color.Yellow;
            }

            document.SaveToFile("FindHighlight.docx", FileFormat.Docx);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("FindHighlight.docx");
        }
    }
}
```